# List superuser processes

Tags: ps, process-management

I am trying to list the superusers processes currently running in my Kali distro. Using "`pgrep -f sbin`" I figured that would do the trick, however it only lists the PID numbers, not the actual name of the processes. How can I get it to do this?

Using `"ps ef | grep "sbin"` it returns a very unformatted list, is there a neat way to format this or dump it to a textfile with some proper formation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding the `-l` flag to `pgrep`:

```
pgrep -lf sbin
```

From `man pgrep`:

```
   -l, --list-name
          List the process name as well as the process ID.  (pgrep only.)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding `-u root` to the ps command?

This will limit it to just roots processes. i.e. `ps -ef -u root | grep sbin`.

To control the output you need to look at the `OUTPUT FORMAT CONTROL` section in the man pages. Just play with the flags until you get the desired/acceptable output?